# PNPM linking with standalone NextJS build

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, pnpm

I'm trying to create production Dockerfile using NextJS standalone mode and PNPM.

In `next.config.js` i have output configuration:

```
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
    outputFileTracingRoot: path.join(__dirname, '../../'),
  },
```

And in Dockerfile I'm using multi-stage build:

```
# BUILD STEP
FROM node:16.13-alpine as landing-builder
WORKDIR /dml-sdk

COPY ./pnpm-workspace.yaml .
COPY ./pnpm-lock.yaml .
COPY ./tsconfig.base.json .
COPY ./package.json .

COPY ./apps/landing ./apps/landing

RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN apk --no-cache add git
RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm@6
RUN pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store

RUN pnpm i
RUN pnpm build

# RUNNER STEP
FROM node:16.13-alpine as landing-runner
WORKDIR /dml-sdk

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=landing-builder /dml-sdk/apps/landing/public ./public
COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/apps/landing/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/node_modules ./node_modules

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV PORT 3010

EXPOSE 3010

WORKDIR /dml-sdk/apps/landing

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

For some reason I'm running into error:

```
landing    | Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/next-server'
landing    | Require stack:
landing    | - /powerplay-sdk/apps/landing/server.js
```

Looks like the next-server is not bundled in `standalone` directory, and line:

```
const NextServer = require('next/dist/server/next-server').default
```

is linked to root node_modules, instead of `/dml-sdk/standalone/apps/landing/node_modules`:

```
node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.0.8_react-dom@17.0.2+react@17.0.2/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.d.ts
```

Is it possible to disable next-server link in BUILD step, so that `standalone` node_modules would include `next-server`?

Comment: Can you try to remove this line `COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/node_modules ./node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

I gess problem in

```
COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/apps/landing/.next/standalone ./
```

It will copy `standalone` file/folder to your workdir from `WORKDIR /dml-sdk`. So you get  `/dml-sdk/standalone`.
Try next

```
COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/apps/landing/.next/standalone ./apps/landing/.next/standalone
```

or

```
COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/apps ./apps
```

or

```
COPY --from=landing-builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /dml-sdk/apps/landing ./apps/landing
```